# Bold Table Bars Removal using ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have an Invoice Image which contains table bars as below example.

[image]

I am using ImageMagick to pre-process Images using the below command.

```
convert 0.png -type Grayscale -negate -define morphology:compose=darken -morphology Thinning 'Rectangle:1x80+0+0<' -negate 0.png
```

My Problem is that output with horizontal bold bars. ImageMagick fails to convert it correctly and output as below.

[image]

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different way using ImageMagick and connected components. First trim the image to remove the outer white, then use connected components to get the id of the largest black region, which should be id=0. The run it again removing the id of the largest area making it transparent and finally flattening the result against white. Then add the thinning operation to remove the horizontal lines that were  not fully black. See https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php

```
convert image.png -fuzz 5% -trim +repage \
-bordercolor black -border 1 \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
null:

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 953x205+0+0 478.7,65.6 31513 srgba(0,0,0,1)
  10789: 943x19+5+184 488.4,193.1 16885 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  1: 465x17+5+1 237.0,9.0 7905 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  2: 474x17+474+1 733.5,9.0 7096 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  3820: 281x21+667+67 807.0,76.9 5609 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  5195: 281x21+667+90 807.0,99.9 5609 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  7959: 281x20+667+137 807.0,146.4 5328 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  9341: 281x20+667+160 807.0,169.5 5328 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  6540: 281x20+667+114 807.0,123.4 5295 srgba(255,255,255,1)
  2375: 281x19+667+46 807.0,55.0 5047 srgba(255,255,255,1)
...

convert image.png -fuzz 5% -trim +repage \
-bordercolor black -border 1 \
-define connected-components:remove=0 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
-background white -flatten \
-negate \
-define morphology:compose=darken \
-morphology Thinning 'Rectangle:1x80+0+0<' \
-negate \
result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried it but I have output as a white image. https://ibb.co/jzX0kq

Comment: What is your version of ImageMagick and the date associated with it. By version, it needs to be 6.8.9.10 or higher just for the basic connected components. But the define for mean-color=true came even later. If on Linux, note that they do not always upgrade the version when they patch and so the patch date is more important. However, someone else had a similar issue earlier (thought they got all dark) and it seemed that their Linux distro did not fully or properly patch ImageMagick even though the date was current. So the person could not get proper results.

Comment: Try this test to see if you even have a version compatible with connected components in ImageMagick. If it works, you should get a list like above `convert image.png -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components 4 null:`. If you do not even get a list, then you do not have a version capable of even the basic connected components processing.

Comment: I get this list : `Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area):
  1: 951x203+19+0 +496.9,+61.7 29201
  12514: 943x19+23+183 +507.8,+192.1 16732
  2: 465x17+23+0 +255.0,+8.0 7905
  4: 37x203+970+0 +988.0,+101.0 7511
  3: 474x17+492+0 +752.4,+7.9 7063`</br> not same number but i had the list.  `Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-28 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib`

Comment: Your version was likely when testing the basic connected components. But the date is 9/29/18, so it should have been patched to be current. Someone else complained the same about it not working in 6.8.9.9 Ubuntu, I believe. So I think they likely did not patch for updates, but only for security issues. You should check with them. You seem to be missing either or both `-define connected-components:remove=0` 
`-define connected-components:mean-color=true`, if you cannot reproduce my result. Your result is not showing any color values, which again makes me think it was version in development.